# Dataframe pandas split str

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I got a dataframe that contains columns with numbers where some are a single number (1234) and others contains multiple numbers(12340-567-8900)
I found a way to split the multiple numbers, but if my columns contains single numbers my code fails.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
    `lens = df['EPDNr'].str.split('-').map(len)
     res = pd.DataFrame({'Title':np.repeat(df['Title'],lens),
                'Kundenummer':np.repeat(df['Kundenummer'],lens),
                'Avvikstype':np.repeat(df['Avvikstype'],lens),
                'Ordrenummer':np.repeat(df['Ordrenummer'],lens),
                'EPDNr':chainer(df['EPDNr']),
               'Antall':chainer(df['Antall'])})
```

I want my output to look like
 Column header: EPDNR
Cell a1 1234
Cell a2 12340
Cell a3 567
cell a4 8900 ect..

Comment: Can you provide more complete sample dataset and expected outputs from that data set?

Comment: `pd.Series(['1234-567-8900','1234']).str.split('-').str[0]
`

Answer (score 2):

You can use expand=True:

```
In [11]: s = pd.Series(["1234-567-8900", "12"])

In [12]: s.str.split("-", expand=True)
Out[12]:
      0     1     2
0  1234   567  8900
1    12  None  None
```